# how to get the trigger if the button was click in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Here's my condition (the commented line):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button7.Click



    'If button1 is Click Then
    '   form1.Show
    '    Panel2.Hide()
    'elseif button2 is click then
    '   form2.show
    '    Panel2.Hide()
    'elseif button 7 is click then
    '    form3.show
    '     Panel2.Hide()
    'else
    '   msgbox("nothing have clicked")
    'End If


End Sub
```

And I suppose that this kind of my condition should work, how do I get the trigger if the button was click in vb.net?

Comment: What does "get the trigger" mean???  The `sender` argument is the item that was clicked

Comment: like if the button is currently on click event or already been clicked

Comment: I have no idea what that means either.  `sender` is probably what you are looking for

Comment: he is combining buttons into a single handler and needs to know which button is calling.

Comment: Exactly @Trevor, would it be possible if I made condition to these buttons when they are clicked? I tried several methods like PerformClick(), I don't know what I am missing coz they keep in getting error

Comment: `If sender is Button1 Then` but better to have 3 separate handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button7.Click

   Dim BT As Button = CType(sender, Button)

   Select Case BT.Name
        Case Button1.Name
            form1.Show
            Panel2.Hide()

        Case Button2.Name
           ...whatever

        Case Button7.Name
            ...whatever

   End Select     
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button7.Click

   If Sender Is Button1
            form1.Show
            Panel2.Hide()

   ElseIf Sender Is Button2
           ...whatever

   ElseIf Sender Is Button7
            ...whatever

   End if
End Sub
```

But you are usually better to have separate handlers for each. One would only combine them if they have a very common theme.